# Drawable in Android flavor can't be resolved in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-productflavors

I have an App with two product flavors, let's call them "apple" and "orange". They share most of the functionality, and have been setup fine. They currently have some different code paths and use different String.xml files and it works fine.

"apple" is now getting new activities and drawables that will only be used in "apple" for now. So I tried adding them to the flavor-specific drawables folders.

I can find and access those drawables in the code using "R.drawables...". However, when I try to add it to an XML layout file, that is also specific to the flavor, I can't access it. It shows "Cannot resolve symbol @drawable/...".

What am I doing wrong?

My folder structure is like this:

```
src
|-- apple
|   |-- java           <-- I can use the drawable programmatically from here
|   |-- res
|       |-- drawable   <-- the new drawable is here
|       |-- layout     <-- the new layout using the drawable is here
|       |-- values
|-- orange
|   |-- java
|   |-- res
|       |-- drawable
|       |-- layout
|       |-- values
|-- main
    |-- java
    |-- res
        |-- drawable
        |-- layout
        |-- values
```

The drawable is an XML in src/apple/res/drawable. The layout XML file is in src/apple/res/layout and looks like this for now (the drawable is called ic_shopping):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping"
    />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you solved that?